# fetching all the link list type using browse button

Tags: development, web-part, list

I have created a webpart. In webpart property I have put a browse button and using that I have to fetch all the list which are of Links List type. So that I can select a list and save into my web part.

Can anyone help me fetching the list that How to fetch all the lists which are of Links list type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like:

```
List<SPList> linkLists = new List<SPList>();
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
foreach(SPList list in web.Lists) {
   if(list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Links) {
      linkLists.Add(list);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MBSurf, for your suggestion. But the thing is I have to put a Browse button and I have to show all the list address there for selection.

Comment: @Ankit: Sounds like you have some code to write! I don't expect @MBSurf to write all of the code for you. :)